Postgres Windowing over a repeating range
Using Postgres, how would I go about querying the below data to return repeating partitions of is_on:



open_time
close_time
is_on




2024-11-05
2024-11-06
true


2024-11-06
2024-11-07
false


2024-11-07
2024-11-08
false


2024-11-08
2024-11-11
false


2024-11-11
2024-11-12
true


2024-11-12
2024-11-13
true



So that the result is:



ot
ct
is_on




2024-11-05
2024-11-06
true


2024-11-06
2024-11-11
false


2024-11-11
2024-11-13
true



I have tried numerous combination of "ROWS UNBOUNDED" to no avail.  The crux of my PARTITION BY being:
OVER (PARTITION BY is_on ORDER BY open_time)  partitioning over everything instead of based on the change in value.
Also note that the range is ot is open_time of the "starting record", close ct is close_time of the "last record" for the band of data.

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One approach uses the difference in row numbers method.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY open_time) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY is_On ORDER BY open_time) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MIN(open_time) AS ot,
    MAX(close_time) AS ct,
    is_on
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    is_on,
    rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    MIN(open_time);

Demo
The above logic works generating a pseudo-group for each block of records belonging to a certain group of the same is_on boolean value.  Then, we aggregate by block and take the earliest open and latest close time.

Tim -big thank you..  Not pretending to fully understand the pattern yet - but will make work of it now - but again thank  you - working like a charm.

@user1210708 Take apart the answer by running SELECT * FROM cte ... then take the difference between rn1 and rn2, you'll see that the combination of this difference and is_on forms a group to identify each block.  The rest should be obvious.

Understand it... Never would have thought to tackle it in this way - for in my mind I was missing some SQL candy as I was convincing myself that I was missing syntax instead of structure.
